# date format in oracle custom

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a table Emp with the dob in the format ddmmyy but I'm not sure how to do it, this is what I've come up with so far

Emp(eno,name,dob);

```
create table Emp(
       eno number constraint c1 as primary key
       , name varchar2(50)
       , dob date
);
```

Comment: alter session set nls_date_format= 'ddmmyy';

Comment: A `date` in Oracle does not have a format.  The client decides how to format the date into a human-readable string.  If the client application doesn't make that decision explicitly, the session's `nls_date_format` would be used.  So the question doesn't make sense.  You've also tagged this for `MySQL` which doesn't make sense given the rest of your question.

Comment: There is no "format" for the storage of a date.  Formatting is a presentation issue, and to convert a DATE type to a string, you call to_char(dob,'DDMMYY')

Comment: exatcly , date format is just a presentation , in dob column you save datetime datatype

Comment: There *is* an internal format for storing dates, obviously, otherwise there would need to be an extra variable needed to decode an arbitrary internal format. What you seem to be doing is conflating `data` with `presentation`. The format for displaying data is in the purview of either the business logic layer (not so good) or with the presentation layer (better). Consider the `alter session` command to be a way for the business logic layer to contain some aspects of the presentation layer.

Comment: @ToniAntunović While some client applications may respect that and use it as the default for displaying dates there are others (including accessing the database via JDBC drivers with Java and C#) that will completely ignore it when displaying dates and will use their own internal defaults instead; so you cannot rely on the NLS session parameters to solve this problem.

Comment: @MT0 you are right, thats why I posted it as a comment not an answer so OP can see if that is what he needed. As JustinCave said the question doesn't make much sense and therefore it is hard to give an definte answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it **NEVER** stores any particular (human-readable) format.

> I want to create a table `Emp` with the `dob` in the format ddmmyy

You cannot as a `DATE` never stores any format.

What you can do is enforce that the time component will always be midnight and, if you wanted the formatting to be managed in the table, you could add a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Emp(
  eno  NUMBER(10,0)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT emp__eno__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(50),
  dob  DATE
       CONSTRAINT emp__dob__chk CHECK (dob = TRUNC(dob)),
  formatted_dob VARCHAR2(6)
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(dob, 'DDMMYY'))
);
```

Then you can:

```sql
INSERT INTO emp (name, dob) VALUES ('Alice', TRUNC(SYSDATE));
```

and the table contains:

> | ENO | NAME | DOB | FORMATTED_DOB |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | 2022-04-26T00:00:00 | 260422 |

*Note: the `dob` column is formatted according to the the configuration of the client application you are using to access the database. In the example above, it is set to use an ISO8601 format.*

However, it is more usual to treat the formatting of a `DATE` as a **display** issue and then you do not need a virtual column and can set whatever format you require in the SQL statement (or in the 3rd party application used to access the database). For example, in SQL you could use:

```sql
SELECT eno,
       name,
       TO_CHAR(dob, 'DDMMYY') AS dob
FROM   emp;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8fceda040a64a550d3f9c5859b8cbd9)*